# Convert 'Long Binary' from CSV file (Originating from MSAccess) to the original file in c#

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, binary

I have a CSV file with the following fields.

> DocPath, Data 
>   C:\CR-12-12-02-03-12-9AM-JG.docx, 0x50004b000300040014000000060000000800000000000 (not the whole thing, it is a massively long string)

The data comes from an MSaccess database but all i have is the CSV.

I need to convert the files back to their original document files or put it into an acceptable format in sql where i can extract them later.  The data was stored in a field type 'long binary' in MSaccess and extracted to this CSV

I have tried researching but have come up empty. Maybe I am asking the wrong questions so I am explaining it here in hopes that someone can help me?

Comment: Any particular reason why the CSV files exist in the first place?  Why not just have Access push the data into SQL?

Comment: I do not have access to the access file, but even if i did, what datatype field would i put the 'long binary' in?

Comment: Well I don't think you have done _"researching"_ on [SQL datatypes](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql+datatypes) because if you did you would know SQL has `binary`; `varbinary` and `image` types.   Give Google a go;  experiement and if you get stuck post your code in a new question here. [ask].  Wishing you well

Comment: _"belittle ppl"_ - golly!!??  What part of _"Wishing you well"_ didn't you understand.  I'm saddened that you think I was belittling you.